# Making all my headings the same font size

Tags: sectioning, fontsize

Im currently finalizing my thesis in Latex and am having a problem making all my headings the same 12 point normal font. How can I make all chapter, section, table of contents and subsection headings normal 12 point un-bolded font?

Comment: Could you provide an MWE? What document class are you even using?

Answer (score 8):

Without knowing anything about your setup, here's something quick you can try:

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\normalsize}
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition the the `sectsty` solution you can also do this with package options and the `titlesec` package:

```
\usepackage[rm,tiny]{titlesec}
```

The `rm` option sets the titles in the normal font, while the `tiny` option makes all headings (except chapter) the same size as the normal font.